# When I start a shell the terminal fills with tilde (~) symbols without my pressing the key

Tags: command-line

When I open a terminal, I see a continuous stream of tilde symbols appearing although I'm not pressing the key.

```
gaurav122197@gaurav122197:~$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~‌​~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~‌
​~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(re‌​peatedly until I close the shell)

Comment: If it continuously types the ~ key, then you've got a stuck key, or a bad keyboard. Turn the keyboard upside down and shake it to release all of the cookie crumbs and see if that helps.

Comment: The key is not stuck as I have no problem in typing in gedit and sublime. When I open some window it gets automatically scrolled down. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 many times but the problem still persists. Please suggest some solution to it.

Comment: I plugged in an external keyboard but the problem still persists. My point is that there is no problem with gedit or atom but with terminal only.

Comment: I've got $100 that says if you unplug the main/internal keyboard, the problem will go away. Use the external keyboard for now.

Comment: Same thing happenning to me. Switched keyboard but still have the problem. I think this is an OS issue, because in windows same keyboard work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your internal/main keyboard continuously types the ~ key, then you've got a stuck key, or a bad keyboard. Seriously, turn the keyboard upside down and shake it to release all of the cookie crumbs and see if that helps.

Hooking up an external keyboard won't disprove this answer. You must disconnect the internal/main keyboard to prove it. While it is unplugged, use an external keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing happened when using PuTTY, but my solution was to change the way a keep-alive app called Caffeine generated it's keep-alive. It was generating F13.

Comment: You are the real MVP. it got me a real headache trying to find the cause

Answer (score 2):

You said that some windows get automatically scrolled down. Your "Page Down" key (which scrolls down windows) might be stuck in, because pressing Page Down creates tildes on the terminal windows for some reason. Try unplugging the bad keyboard from your computer and using a different one.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for this is a faulty keyboard!

<kbd>PGDN</kbd> and function keys <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> create a tilde `~` sign on the terminal. So if any one of these keys on a keyboard is faulty, one will see such behaviour as you mentioned.

We can disable these keys and fix this problem. The procedure is given below:

1. Find the keycode of the faulty key. This can be done by the following command:

   ```
   xmodmap -pke
   ```
2. Disable the key using;

   ```
   xmodmap -e 'keycode of the faulty key'
   ```

   For example, <kbd>F8</kbd> has keycode 74, therefore `xmodmap -e 'keycode 74='`
   will disable <kbd>F8</kbd>.

You may create a bash script to run the command during startup. Then you will not have to run it repeatedly.