# TILDE KEY (~) TYPING REPEATEDTLY ON THE TERMINAL

Tags: boot, keyboard

Hi I just upgraded my Dell Inspiron 15 (3521) from windows OS to Ubuntu 20.04.

After the installation I noticed that anytime I boot my system it will first spin some random messages on the screen as shown in the image before the system load. 
[This is the image to describe the behavior when I am booting the system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1gJG.jpg)

Some times I use CTRL + C to skip it. Other than that the system was working fine.

Until recently when I noticed that most times my screen blink with some random colors and then when I'm on the web browser, the page randomly scroll to the bottom and then I have to scroll back up again and again untill I realized that one of the keys on my keyboard presses randomly and that's why my page always scroll down suddenly.

The key is actually the tilde  ( ~ )  key and I know because I saw it repeatedly on the terminal 
[This is the image of the tilde key in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfCb7.png)

I have navigated to the " Settings > Universal Access > Typing, and set the 'Repeat Keys' to 'Off' " but that only minimize the effect because the key no longer presses continuously but it does it continually.

Please  any idea on what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If you have another keyboard try that and see if the behaviour continous. If you have another Operating System on the same computer check and see if it has the same behaviour. Or try the keyboard on another system. Same behaviour? If it does, clean your keyboard. Problem not solved. Repair your keyboard ( if you can ) or get another keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have an extra keyboard but I will look for one and try it out, thumbs up 

Comment: Thank you @HomerSimpson, I try an external keyboard and the experience is the same.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/946440/when-i-start-a-shell-the-terminal-fills-with-tilde-symbols-without-my-pressi

Comment: @JoepieEs this is pretty helpful, thank you so much. after following the guide provided in the post, I find out that it is my PAGE_DOWN key that is pressing randomly, so I had to disable it and everything is cool. Thanks to everyone who contributed, More power to you all. 